# Reading 65k rows hangs PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, large-data

I am developing a PHP application that processes IP adresses. I am working with mysql tables containing up to 4 billion rows.

I have a script that currently needs to fetch 65536 adresses from this table and the mysql<->php interface fails to give a response via PHP or even via phpMyAdmin when I try to extract these 65K lines. If used in command line, mysql will give the 65K lines without trouble in about 0.2 sec.

The table containing the IP addresses has 3 indexes ( 1 unique, 2 primary ) which are supposed to help it go faster but I simply cannot get past having mysql give an associative array back to PHP in order to continue my data processing.

Server is a dedicated recent Xeon machine with about 32GB memory (I don't know the exact specs).

Any clues about what could be going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Development issues are typically not **[on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)** here, but in general people use their (error) log files to give them a clue. A completely random guess is you have imposed [a memory limit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5925885/2952385) you run into.

Comment: Hi and thx for your answer. I was advised to post in a server related forum via stackoverflow.com because to them it looks like a config issue but was force to provide the symptoms in a coding way since it's code related. I'll try to get my hands on any info available logwise.

Comment: Seems we have a memory limit there, I'll be posting this afternoon to tell if the problem is gone once the admin pushes the limit.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli` and `PDO` both operate in **buffered mode** by default. This means that your queries are effectively subject to the PHP process memory limit.

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php:

> [In buffered mode], query results are immediately transferred from the MySQL Server to PHP
>   and are then kept in the memory of the PHP process. This allows
>   additional operations like counting the number of rows, and moving
>   (seeking) the current result pointer. It also allows issuing further
>   queries on the same connection while working on the result set. The
>   downside of the buffered mode is that larger result sets might require
>   quite a lot memory.

You should either increase the memory limit of PHP processes in your `php.ini` by increasing the `memory_limit` setting or you can tell the queries to use **unbuffered mode**:

> Unbuffered MySQL queries execute the query and then return a resource
>   while the data is still waiting on the MySQL server for being fetched.
>   This uses less memory on the PHP-side, but can increase the load on
>   the server.

**Mysqli example:**

```
$mysqli  = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$uresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

**PDO example:**

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```